# Mysql - Select a certain number of rows for every WHERE IN condition value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select maximum 2 rows for each value in condition

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE department IN (2,3,4);
```

Here is table I have

| department | file |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Innovation Arch |
| 1 | Strat Security |
| 1 | Inspire Fitness Co |
| 1 | Candor Corp |
| 2 | Cogent Data |
| 2 | Epic Adventure Inc |
| 2 | Sanguine Skincare |
| 2 | Vortex Solar |
| 3 | Admire Arts |
| 3 | Bravura Inc |
| 3 | Bonefete Fun |
| 3 | Moxie Marketing |
| 3 | Zeal Wheels |
| 4 | Obelus Concepts |

And this is what I would like to achieve

| department | file |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Cogent Data |
| 2 | Epic Adventure Inc |
| 3 | Moxie Marketing |
| 3 | Zeal Wheels |
| 4 | Obelus Concepts |

**In case if you need:**

```
CREATE TABLE files (department INT, file VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO files (department, file) VALUES
(1, "Innovation Arch"),(1, "Strat Security"),(1, "Inspire Fitness Co"),(1, "Candor Corp"),
(2, "Cogent Data"),(2, "Epic Adventure Inc"),(2, "Sanguine Skincare"),(2, "Vortex Solar"),
(3, "Admire Arts"),(3, "Bravura Inc"),(3, "Bonefete Fun"),(3, "Moxie Marketing"),(3, "Zeal Wheels"),
(4, "Obelus Concepts");
```

Comment: Why doesn't your table have a primary-key?

Comment: *I want to select maximum 2 rows for each value* Which two?What is t he logic behind the result? What have you tried?

Comment: How are the two rows for each to be determined? Or do you want any two random rows?

Comment: @Dai I am not allowed to share the production table, I just created a test case here.

Comment: @kallis Your test-case is currently inadequate.

Comment: @Stu No, the rows can be anythng

Comment: @Dai Sorry dude, but this the table and it is perfectly allowed in Mysql. If the desired outcomes need to have a primary key then you can tell.

Comment: There is no first,second, nth row in sql therefore your desired outcome cannot be guaranteed..

Comment: @Dai Why don't you post an answer that proves the primary key is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "the rows can be anything" you could simply apply a row_number window and filter:

```
select department, file from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by department order by department) rn
  from files
)t
where rn <= 2 and department in (2,3,4);
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cqA_5PNt)

You can also order by *file* to choose two rows alphabetically.

Comment: A lot of new things are there honestly, it will take some time for me to understand but for now I got the result, Thanks.

Comment: Hey, A follow up question WHAT IF.. I put this Query **select department, file from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by department order by department) rn
  from files WHERE department in (2,3,4)
)t
where rn <= 2;** Will it be more efficient